How to setup OIDC for customer environment using .Net Framewrok?
I know this is a complex problem, but we are trying to implement it as simply as possible, yet all documentation code and example code out there does not work out of the box. Im looking for any information that could help in handling OIDC. I already gave up on understanding why/how it works and I am simply interested in making it work. Any help or questions are welcome.
Context of the problem:
3 years ago we implemented OIDC on our website. Simple functionality, check if incoming request is authenticated and sliding expiration. When developing, I gave up after a month, because the "according to documentation" solution did not work in any shape or form. So I added additional configuration until basic authentication worked and had to manually handle cookies (custom cookie manager), sliding experation. This solution worked for up until 4 months ago, when suddenly it did not work anymore. We could not figure out what changed and also what exactly breaks. Customers did not provide any new information and cant/wont help with debugging or how the server on their side is configured.
So we gave up fixing the custom solution and started fresh. Following documentation, once again nothing works, not even redirecting to the login page. With the following code, we have partial success. It redirects to login page, user can log in, but no sliding expiration and when the authentication cookie expires it does not redirect to login, but throws an error.
My suspicion is that we are missing some values or specifics to our customers configuration, but as they are not sharing information I can only guess. So im not sure if it is relevant information. We just received word that my previous custom solution is once again working, but only for one of the customers. The difference between that customer and another we tried is how the MFA is being handled. Customer A (where it works) MFA includes
"acr_value" and AuthorizationCodeChallange, because they told us it was required. Even though the old custom solution technically works, I still would like to understand how and why do I have so much trouble implementing a seemingly basic solution.
Environment description:
.NET Framework 4.8 MVC website. It is part of a larger project, but for the purposes of this issue its a simple website, where we are simply trying to log in and correctly maintain that connection, when user interracts with the website and invalidate their session when set time expired.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect 7.5.1
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect 4.2.2
In detail descriptions:
App configuration for OIDC happens in the following order with a very bare AuthorizeAttribute.

UseExternalSignInCookie
SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType
UseCookieAuthentication
UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication

UseExternalSignInCookie:
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType:
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
UseCookieAuthentication:
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    CookieSameSite = Microsoft.Owin.SameSiteMode.None,
    CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
    CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
});

private static bool IsSessionExpired(CookieValidateIdentityContext Context)
{
    return (Context.Properties.IssuedUtc + Context.Options.ExpireTimeSpan) < DateTime.UtcNow;
}

UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication:
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = oidcConfig.ClientId,
    ClientSecret = oidcConfig.ClientSecret,
    Scope = oidcConfig.Scope, //value: "openid"
    Authority = oidcConfig.Authority,
    RedirectUri = oidcConfig.RedirectUri, //value: "https://website.gg/signin-oidc"
    ResponseType = oidcConfig.ResponseType, //value: "code"
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = oidcConfig.SignInAsAuthenticationType, //value: "Cookies"
    AuthenticationType = oidcConfig.AuthenticationType, 
    ResponseMode = oidcConfig.ResponseMode, //value: "query"
    SaveTokens = oidcConfig.ToBool(oidcConfig.SaveTokens), //value: "true"
    UseTokenLifetime = oidcConfig.ToBool(oidcConfig.UseTokenLifetime), //value: "true"
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = oidcConfig.PostLogoutRedirectUri, //value: "https://website.gg/signout-callback-oidc"
    RequireHttpsMetadata = oidcConfig.ToBool(oidcConfig.RequireHttpsMetadata), 
    RedeemCode = true,
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateLifetime = oidcConfig.ValidateLifetime, //value: "true"
        SaveSigninToken = oidcConfig.SaveSigninToken,
        ValidIssuer = oidcConfig.ValidIssuer != null ? oidcConfig.ValidIssuer : oidcConfig.Authority,// The issuer to be validated
        ValidAudience = oidcConfig.ValidAudience != null ? oidcConfig.ValidAudience : oidcConfig.ClientId,// The Audience to be validated
    },
    ProtocolValidator = new OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator()
    {
        RequireNonce = oidcConfig.ToBool(oidcConfig.RequireNonce), //value: "true"
        RequireStateValidation = oidcConfig.ToBool(oidcConfig.RequireStateValidation),
        RequireTimeStampInNonce = oidcConfig.ToBool(oidcConfig.RequireTimeStampInNonce), //value: "true"
    },

    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        },
        AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
        {
            logger.Debug("AuthorizationCodeReceived called...");
                        try
                        {
                            if (oidcConfig.DiscoverEndpoints)
                            {
                                var disco = await n.Options.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(n.OwinContext.Request.CallCancelled);
                                oidcConfig.TokenEndpoint = disco.TokenEndpoint;
                                oidcConfig.UserinfoEndpoint = disco.UserInfoEndpoint;
                                oidcConfig.EndsessionEndpoint = disco.EndSessionEndpoint;
                                oidcConfig.WebKeySetEndpoint = disco.JwksUri;
                            }
                            var client = new HttpClient();

                            var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, oidcConfig.TokenEndpoint)
                            {
                                Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(n.TokenEndpointRequest.Parameters)
                            };
                            var tokenResponse = await n.Options.Backchannel.SendAsync(tokenRequest);
                            var tokenContent = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                            var accessToken = JObject.Parse(tokenContent)["access_token"].ToString();
                            var idToken = JObject.Parse(tokenContent)["id_token"].ToString();

                            //identity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", accessToken));
                            logger.Debug("accessToken: " + accessToken);
                            //logger.Debug("identityToken: " + identityToken);
                            //n.AuthenticationTicket = authenticationTicket;
                            OpenIdConnectMessage message = new OpenIdConnectMessage(tokenContent);
                            n.HandleCodeRedemption(message);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            logger.Error(ex);
                        }
        },
        AuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            logger.Debug("AuthenticationFailed called...");
            context.HandleResponse();
            context.Response.Redirect("/");
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        },
        SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
        {
            try
            {
                var userinforequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, oidcConfig.UserinfoEndpoint)
                {
                    Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(n.ProtocolMessage.Parameters)
                };
                var response = await n.Options.Backchannel.SendAsync(userinforequest);
                var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                logger.Debug("JSON=" + responseContent);

                OpenIdConnectMessage message = new OpenIdConnectMessage(responseContent);

                var json = Json.Decode(responseContent);
                string user = json[oidcConfig.UserID].ToString();

                logger.Debug("user: " + user);
                var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user)
                };

                n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaims(claims);

                var identity = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                var properties = n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties;

                logger.Debug("Sign in called...");
                n.OwinContext.Authentication.SignIn(properties, identity);
                logger.Debug("Sign in HttpContext called...");
                HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(properties, identity);
                logger.Debug("AuthenticationTicket IsAuthenticated: " + n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
                logger.Debug("OwinContext IsAuthenticated: " + n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
                logger.Debug("HTTP_OWIN_CONTEXT IsAuthenticated: " + HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
                logger.Debug("HTTP_OWIN_CONTEXT IsAuthenticated: " + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
                logger.Debug("OIDC-Notification: SecurityTokenValidated Processed");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex);
            }
        }
    },
});

AuthorizeAttribute:
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
        public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
        {

            private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

            protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
            {
                bool disableAuthentication = false;

                if (!AppSettingsKey.LoginEnabled.Enabled)
                    disableAuthentication = true;


                if (disableAuthentication)
                    return true;

                return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
            }

            protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
            {
                logger.Debug("Entered HandleUnauthorizedRequest in CustomAuthorize class.");
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }

            public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (AppSettingsKey.LoginEnabled.Enabled && AppSettingsKey.OpenIdConnectSSOEnabled.Enabled)
                    {
                        logger.Debug("Entered OnAuthorization method.");
                        logger.Debug("Request Url: "+HttpContext.Current.Request.Url);
                        logger.Debug("Request UserAgent: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent);
                        logger.Debug("Request UrlReferrer: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer);
                        logger.Debug("Request UserHostName: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName);
                        logger.Debug("SessionID: "+HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID);
                        logger.Debug("UserName: " + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
                        logger.Debug("Is authenticated Auth.User: " + HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
                        logger.Debug("Is authenticated User: " + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
                        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    logger.Error(e, "Exception while overriding the OnAuthorization method.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

Additional information:
We are really unsure on our customers' setup so that can be a valid answer. If I left out anything or if something is unclear I will do my best to provide more information.
All in all, I am looking for some insight, why the basic examples do not work or how to enable basic features as sliding expiration. For example, almost all basic examples do not have reference to "RedirectToIdentityProvider" notification, yet I cant make it work without having it (also note that it has no code in it).
I do not expect anyone to come  and just solve the whole thing, but I am stuck so please send help.
